# Factoring $2x^2 - 7x-4$

Tags: calculus, factoring

This is an example from the Stewart's Review of Algebra - https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/ESSENTIAL%20CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/ess-reviewofalgebra.pdf

It is on page $3$, example $5$.
This is what it suggests on the book

*Even though the coefficient of $x^2$ is not $1$, we can still look for factors of the form $2x+r$
and $x+s$, where $rs=-4$. Experimentation reveals that:
$2x^2-7x-4=(2x+1)(x-4)$*

Now, I have no idea what they mean by "experimentation" there. I had $2$ ways to find the solution of this problem: Use Vieta's Theorem or divide the equation by $2$ so the coefficient of a is $1$, factor it using $(x+r)(x+s)$ and then add the coefficient $2$ back.
I still have a feeling that none of the methods I tried were the one suggested by the author.
Can anyone explain what the author meant by "experimentation" and how he came to that solution?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: By experimentation the author just means "trying some values of $r$ and $s$".

Comment: I pity those forced to learn from those books.

Comment: The discriminant is a square, namely 81. The roots, found by the quadratic formula, are rational . Find them, call them $r_1$ and $r2,$  The original factors as $2(x-r_1)(x-r_2).$  Finally, it is guaranted that the $2$  can be absorbed into one of the factors to arrange integer coefficients all around,

Comment: The question is, if I am to solve this on an exam would the way I did it be considered correct? I hardly doubt that solving this by trial and error is the real way as there might be a similar example where trial and error is very unpractical...
@Will Jagy, yeah that is how I solved it using Vieta's Theorem, I was curious to find out how the author expected me to solve it.

Comment: Evil, do you know the quadratic formula? Are you able to use it to find the roots of $2x^2 - 7x - 4 \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: If you are to solve this in an exam, you can use [the way that is known since more than 4000 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: Yes, I solved it the way you suggested it, finding the discriminant, then finding the roots of x1 and x2, then factor it according to Vieta's theorem: a(x-x1)(x-x2). My question here isn't finding the solution of this problem as I already know how to do it. I wanted to find out how the author expected me to solve this which seems different than the way I have done it.

Comment: Then I am glad to know the author didn't have a mysterious third way to solve this.

Comment: The only ‘experimentation’ I can imagine consists in using the *rational roots theorem*, but as this factorisation is a standard high school exercise on quadratic polynomials…

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse: [This](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-grouping/a/factoring-quadratics-leading-coefficient-not-1) article outlines a simpler method for how to factorise the quadratic. I've used it in my answer.

Comment: Very nice, I guess I'll go through the whole thing and not just that subsection to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$2x^2-7x-4=(2x+r)(x+s)=2x^2+(r+2s)x+rs,$$then $rs=-4$ and $r+2s=-7$. I suspect the what the author is suggesting here is to take all pairs  $(r,s)$ of integers such that $rs=-4$ (there are only $6$ such pairs), and to see whether or net we have $r+2s=-7$ for one such pair. And the answer is affirmative: the pair $(1,-4)$ will work.

Comment: So, the author didn't really solve it but just plugged in a few pairs till he got it right?

Comment: It looks like, yes. But they were not just random pairs; they were the only $6$ pairs of integers for which the product is $-4$.

Comment: I have no idea why the author went with this "experimentation" instead of actually solving it :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are beginning - where you have reason to suspect the factors are likely to be "nice"  (here meaning that the roots are rational) you can assume $(2x+r)(x+s)$ with $r$ and $s$ integers (not just rational numbers). If you are wrong in your assumption, you have extra work.

Whether the answer is considered correct depends on the precise question. If you are asked to find a factorisation then any method (including trial and error will do).

If the equation $px^2+qx+r=0$ with $p, q, r$ being integers and $p$ a prime has rational roots, then one of the roots is an integer factor of $r$ (may be positive or negative). This is a consequence of the fact that $p$ is a prime. If $\alpha$ is a root, then $(x-\alpha)$ is a factor. So, since $2$ is a prime, that is easy.

Comment: Thank you, one thing I wanted to know is if when the equation is in the form of x^2+bx+c, we factor it using (x+r)(x+s) but if the coefficient of x is something other than 1, then why is it not (2x+r)(2x+s) but instead (2x+r)(x+s)?

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse If you multiply out your brackets the term in $x^2$ will be $2x\cdot 2x=4x^2$. In general $(px+q)(rx+s)=prx^2+(ps+qr)x+qs$

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the given quadratic is factorable (over integers), to get the $x^2$-term to come out right, you would need $(2x...)(x...)$.  Because the given quadratic has no common integer factor (greater than $1$) of the three coefficients, we must have that neither factor in the factorization has a common integer factor. So there will have to be   $\pm 1$ with the $2x$ factor, and correspondingly $\mp 4$ with the $x$ factor. So there are only two possibilities to check.

(This goes faster with practice...a lot faster than the explanation!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method for factorising quadratics that reduces the amount of trial and error needed. To factorise any quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$, you need to find two numbers that have a sum of $b$ and a product of $ac$. In your example of $2x^2-7x-4$, we need to find two numbers that sum to make $-7$ and multiply to make $-8$. Inspection tells us that those numbers are $-8$ and $+1$. Then, you should split up the middle term of the quadratic like so:
\begin{align}
2x^2\color{red}{-7}x-4 &= 2x^2\color{red}{-8}x+\color{red}{1}x-4 \\[5pt]
&= 2x(x-4)+(x-4) \\[5pt]
&= (2x+1)(x-4) \, .
\end{align}
See [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-grouping/a/factoring-quadratics-leading-coefficient-not-1) article for more information. Ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: Can you explain how you went form the 2nd to the 3rd step?

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse: I presume you are talking about how $2x(x-4)+(x-4)=(2x+1)(x-4)$. There are two ways to explain this: if we let $k=x-4$, then $$2x(x-4)+(x-4)=2xk+k=k(2x+1)=(x-4)(2x+1) = (2x+1)(x-4) \, .$$So we are just taking out a factor of $k$. The second way to understand is that we have $2x$ lots of $(x-4)$, plus $1$ lot of $(x-4)$, which is the same as $(2x+1)$ lots of $(x-4)$. Does that make sense? If not, I can elaborate further.

Comment: Note that my above comment had a typo. I've edited it out now.

Comment: Thank you, it is perfectly clear now.

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse: I'm very glad I could help. If you have any more questions, then let me know.